# JQuery DatePicker Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having an issue when the date from JQuery DatePicker is selected and used as a variable in my SQL Statement. It brings up an error saying invalid datetime string even when I formatted it using DateTime.Parse or Convert.DateTime.

JQuery DatePicker

```
   <script>
  $( function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        altField: "#ContentPlaceHolder1_selectDate",
          defaultDate: $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultDate').val(),
          dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
          onSelect: function (date, obj) {
              $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultDate').val(date);
              $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_selectDate').val(date)
              $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultDate').trigger('change');
              $('#form1').submit();  
          },
    });
      });
  </script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     onLoad:   $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultDate').val($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_selectDate').val());
    });
  </script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="text" id="defaultDate" runat="server"/>
<input type="text" id="selectDate" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

**UPDATE:**
This issue is the Postback. If I do this code. It works fine

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string defDate = selectDate.Value;
        DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(defDate);
        label1.Text = DT.ToShortDateString();
     }
```

However this causes the error message

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string defDate = selectDate.Value.Replace('-', '/');
        DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(defDate);
        label1.Text = DT.ToShortDateString();
     }
```

This code works

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string defDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(defDate);
        label1.Text = DT.ToShortDateString();
    }
  else
    {
        string defDate = selectDate.Value.Replace('-', '/');
        DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(defDate);
        label1.Text = DT.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Can someone explain the reason for this?

Comment: `mm` stands for minutes, you probably meant `MM`

Comment: @Rafalon "mm" will show the month number "MM" shows the month name

Comment: Not in C#: [Custom Date and Time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) `M` and `MM` shows the month number on one or two digits, `MMM` and `MMMM` shows short or long month name

Comment: @Rafalon I changed it to MM but I still get an error

Comment: @Rafalon no it passes as a string. I thought the same thing. But when I just used selectDate.value by itself I got an error saying "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime."

Comment: Maybe because you should use `datepicker` instead of `selectDate`, don't you think? Or `<input type="date"` instead of `<input type="text"` for `selectDate`. If you use this, note that `selectDate.Value` will be a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 4):

DateTime.Parse only takes 4 different formats.

```
2018-09-14
09/14/2018
Sep 14 2018
14 Sep 2018
```

It will not accept `mm-dd-yy` format.

Try replacing the `-` with `/` like the following.

```
defDate.replace('-', '/');
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and I am still getting an error message. I have updated the code.

Comment: @DanNick Might be an issue with selectDate.Value. Seems your DatePicker is called 'datepicker' so try datepicker.value instead pf selectedDate

Comment: That did not work. I updated the code. I got the code working but I do not know why? On initial Page Load is the DatePicker not setting the default date to today?